# How to add qty on category page for newer versions of OpenCart?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3

There are posts about adding qty to category page for other versions, but not for the newer 3.x Opencart.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what went wrong?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to make it more specific/clear (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.